# Click event isn't working on iOS and Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

I have checked several forums and MDN [Element: click event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event) and tried over 10 solutions I understand it has to do with a bug in iOS, can anyone guide me or explain what needs to be changed so that the output will display on iOS/Safari mobile and desktop. For some reason this output only displays on Windows and Android when the button is clicked but nothing happens on iOS/ Safari environment.

```js
const firstItem = document.querySelector('#first-item')
const secondItem = document.querySelector('#second-item');
const year = document.querySelector('#year');
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
const output = document.querySelector('.output');
const outputText = document.querySelector('.output-text');
// footer date
const footerDate = document.querySelector('.footer-p');
let date = new Date().getFullYear();

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  getResult();
});


function getResult() {
  btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    let firstItemValue = firstItem.value;
    let secondItemValue = secondItem.value;
    let yearValue = year.value;
    // 30 percent off first item
    function thirtyPercentOff() {
      return firstItemValue * .7
    }
    // add cost
    function addCost() {
      return secondItemValue * parseInt(yearValue)
    }
    // define result and too expensive
    let result = Math.floor(thirtyPercentOff() - addCost());
    let expensive = addCost() > (thirtyPercentOff() / 5);
    // result with commas
    function numberWithCommas(result) {
      return result.toString().replace(/\B(?<!\.\d*)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    }

    // in case of discrepancy and the cost is higher then the first item price / 5   
    if (result < 0 || expensive) {
      output.textContent = `*This item has additional costs: $${numberWithCommas(addCost())}`
      output.classList.add('cover')

    } else if (firstItemValue !== '' && secondItemValue !== '') {
      // max cash offer
      output.textContent = `$${numberWithCommas(result)}`
      output.classList.remove('cover')
    }
  })




}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.main {
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: BlinkMacSystemFont;
  margin: auto;
  width: 500px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  margin-bottom: 140px;
}

img {
  width: 200px;
}

header {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px 0px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
}

header h2 {
  font-size: 34px;
}

header h3 {
  margin: 20px 0px;
}

p.comment {
  margin: 8px 0px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

input[type=text],
select {
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

button.btn {
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #306cec;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.clickable {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.output-text {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
}

.output-text {
  margin-right: 40px;
  float: right;
}

.cover {
  background-color: #ce3e06;
  color: white;
  height: 100px;
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #306cec;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.footer-p {
  margin: 40px 0px;
  text-align: center;
}


/**** media queries  *****/


/* Media Query for Mobile Devices */

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .footer {
    display: none;
  }
  .main {
    width: 300px;
    padding: 20px 30px 50px 30px;
  }
  .output-offer {
    padding: 0px 0px 180px 0px;
  }
}


/* Media Query for low resolution  Tablets, Ipads */

@media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  .main {
    width: 500px;
    padding: 20px 30px 30px 30px;
  }
}


/* Media Query for Tablets Ipads portrait mode */

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .main {
    width: 500px;
    padding: 20px 30px 30px 30px;
  }
}


/* Media Query for Laptops and Desktops */

@media (min-width: 1025px) and (max-width: 1280px) {
  .main {
    width: 500px;
    padding: 20px 30px 30px 30px;
  }
}


/* Media Query for Large screens */

@media (min-width: 1281px) {
  .main {
    width: 500px;
    padding: 20px 30px 30px 30px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#" type="image/x-icon">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Form Name</title>
</head>

<body>
  <section class="main">
    <header>
      <img src="#" alt="img">
      <h2>Form Name</h2>
    </header>
    <form>
      <!-- label first-item -->
      <label for="first-item">Item Price</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first-item" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');" placeholder="item price in $" required/>
      <!-- label second-item  -->
      <label for="second-item">second item value</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="second-item" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');" placeholder="Enter second value" required/>

      <label for="year">Year</label>
      <select id="year">
        <option value="35">1985</option>
        <option value="65">1975 - 1985</option>
        <option value="75">1975</option>
      </select>
      <button type="submit" href="#" onclick="event.preventDefault(); return false;" class="btn clickable">Submit</button>
      <!-- <btn "> -->
    </form>

    <h3 class="output" href="#footer_id">
      <span>Output:</span> <span class="output-text"></span>
    </h3>
  </section>




  <!-- end of section-->
  <script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: After getting answers from a different source, Safari doesent support regular expressions so they must be removed, also jQuery was used instead of JavaScript as the click event. And instead of onclick="event.preventDefault();  I used onclick="javascript: return false;"                            for now this solution works... working example below tedted on ios/chrome/win environment.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const firstItem = document.querySelector('#first-item')
const secondItem = document.querySelector('#second-item');
const option = document.querySelector('#option');
const output = document.querySelector('.output');
const outputText = document.querySelector('.output-text');
// footer date
const footerDate = document.querySelector('.footer-p');
let date = new Date().getFullYear();



$(function() {
  $(".btn").on('click', function() {
    let firstItemValue = firstItem.value;
    let secondItemValue = secondItem.value;
    let optionValue = option.value;
    // 30 percent off first item
    function thirtyPercentOff() {
      return firstItemValue * .7
    }
    // add cost
    function addCost() {
      return secondItemValue * parseInt(optionValue)
    }
    // define result and too expensive
    let result = Math.floor(thirtyPercentOff() - addCost());
    let expensive = addCost() > (thirtyPercentOff() / 150 - 14);
    // result with commas
    function numberWithCommas(result) {
      return result.toLocaleString('en', {
        maximumSignificantDigits: 21
      })
    }

    // in case of discrepancy and the cost is higher then the first item price / 5   
    if (result < 0 || expensive) {
      output.textContent = `*This item has additional costs: $${numberWithCommas(addCost())}`


    } else if (firstItemValue !== '' && secondItemValue !== '') {
      // max cash offer
      output.textContent = `$${numberWithCommas(result)}`

    }

  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.main {
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: BlinkMacSystemFont;
  margin: auto;
  width: 500px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  margin-bottom: 140px;
}

img {
  width: 200px;
}

header {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px 0px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
}

header h2 {
  font-size: 34px;
}

header h3 {
  margin: 20px 0px;
}

p.comment {
  margin: 8px 0px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

input[type=text],
select {
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

button.btn {
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #306cec;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.clickable {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.output-text {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
}

.output-text {
  margin-right: 40px;
  float: right;
}

.cover {
  background-color: #ce3e06;
  color: white;
  height: 100px;
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #306cec;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.footer-p {
  margin: 40px 0px;
  text-align: center;
}


/**** media queries  *****/


/* Media Query for Mobile Devices */

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .footer {
    display: none;
  }
  .main {
    width: 300px;
    padding: 20px 30px 50px 30px;
  }
  .output-offer {
    padding: 0px 0px 180px 0px;
  }
}


/* Media Query for low resolution  Tablets, Ipads */

@media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  .main {
    width: 500px;
    padding: 20px 30px 30px 30px;
  }
}


/* Media Query for Tablets Ipads portrait mode */

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .main {
    width: 500px;
    padding: 20px 30px 30px 30px;
  }
}


/* Media Query for Laptops and Desktops */

@media (min-width: 1025px) and (max-width: 1280px) {
  .main {
    width: 500px;
    padding: 20px 30px 30px 30px;
  }
}


/* Media Query for Large screens */

@media (min-width: 1281px) {
  .main {
    width: 500px;
    padding: 20px 30px 30px 30px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#" type="image/x-icon">
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Form Name</title>
</head>

<body>
  <section class="main">
    <header>
      <img src="#" alt="img">
      <h2>Form Name</h2>
    </header>
    <form>
      <!-- label first-item -->
      <label for="first-item">first item value</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first-item" placeholder="item price in $" required/>
      <!-- label second-item  -->
      <label for="second-item">second item value</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="second-item" placeholder="Enter second value" required/>

      <label for="option">option</label>
      <select id="option">
        <option value="35">A</option>
        <option value="65">B</option>
        <option value="75">C</option>
      </select>
      <button type="submit" onclick="javascript: return false;" class="btn clickable">Submit</button>
      <!-- <btn "> -->
    </form>

    <h3 class="output" href="#footer_id">
      <span>Output:</span> <span class="output-text"></span>
    </h3>
  </section>




  <!-- end of section-->
  <script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```